# I get the error of "ReferenceError: accounts is not defined"

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am currently reading 「Hands-On Smart Contract Development with Solidity
and Ethereum」（O’REILLY）and transcribing the code in this book.

I am getting errors and my hands are tied.

The errors are as follows.

> ReferenceError: accounts is not defined
> (/Users/tsuru/fundraiser/test/fundraiser_test.js:59:28)

According to the error, there seems to be a problem with

```
const newBeneficiary = accounts[2];
```

The code is here.

/fundraiser/test/fundraiser_test

```
const FundraiserContract = artifacts.require("Fundraiser");

contract("Fundraiser", accounts => {
let fundraiser;
const name =  "Beneficiary Name";
const url = "[beneficiaryname.org](http://beneficiaryname.org/)";
const imageURL = "[https://placekitten.com/600/350] 
(https://placekitten.com/600/350)";
const description = "Beneficiary description";
const beneficiary = accounts[1];
const owner = accounts[0];

beforeEach(async () => {
fundraiser = await FundraiserContract.new(
name,
url,
imageURL,
description,
beneficiary,
owner
)
});
});

describe("initialization", () => {
it("gets the beneficiary name", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.name();
assert.equal(actual, name, "names should match");
});

it("gets the beneficiary url", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.url();
assert.equal(actual, url, "url should match");
});

it("gets the beneficiary image url", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.imageURL();
assert.equal(actual, imageURL, "imageURL should match");
});

it("gets the beneficiary description", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.description();
assert.equal(actual, description, "description should match");
});

it("gets the beneficiary", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.beneficiary();
assert.equal(actual, beneficiary, "beneficiary addresses should match");
});

it("gets the owner", async () => {
const actual = await fundraiser.owner();
assert.equal(actual, owner, "bios should match");
});
});

describe("setBeneficiary", () => {

//The line where the error is pointed out
const newBeneficiary = accounts[2];

it("updated beneficiary when called by owner account", async () => {
await fundraiser.setBeneficiary(newBeneficiary, {from: owner});
const actualBeneficiary = await fundraiser.beneficiary();
assert.equal(actualBeneficiary, newBeneficiary, "beneficiaries should match");
});


it("throws and error when called from a non-owner account", async () => {
try {
 await fundraiser.setBeneficiary(newBeneficiary, {from: accounts[3]});
 assert.fail("withdraw was not restricted to owners")
} catch(err) {
 const expectedError = "Ownable: caller is not the owner"
 const actualError = err.reason;
 assert.equal(actualError, expectedError, "should not be permitted")
 }
 })
 })
```

contructs/Fundraiser.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Fundraiser is Ownable {

string public name;
string public url;
string public imageURL;
string public description;
address payable public beneficiary;

constructor(
string memory _name,
string memory _url,
string memory _imageURL,
string memory _description,
address payable _beneficiary,
address _custodian
)
public
{
name = _name;
url = _url;
imageURL = _imageURL;
description = _description;
beneficiary = _beneficiary;
transferOwnership(_custodian);
}

function setBeneficiary(address payable _beneficiary) public onlyOwner {
beneficiary = _beneficiary;
}
}
```

All codes can be found here.
https://github.com/okahijiki/fundraiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing contract parentheses early after the `beforeEach` hook. therefore, you have less closing parentheses at the end. this should work:

```
const FundraiserContract = artifacts.require("Fundraiser");

contract("Fundraiser", (accounts) => {
  let fundraiser;
  const name = "Beneficiary Name";
  const url = "[beneficiaryname.org](http://beneficiaryname.org/)";
  // I do not know what kind of syntax is this
  const imageURL =
    "[https://placekitten.com/600/350](https://placekitten.com/600/350)";
  const description = "Beneficiary description";
  const beneficiary = accounts[1];
  const owner = accounts[0];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fundraiser = await FundraiserContract.new(
      name,
      url,
      imageURL,
      description,
      beneficiary,
      owner
    );
  });

  describe("initialization", () => {
    it("gets the beneficiary name", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.name();
      assert.equal(actual, name, "names should match");
    });

    it("gets the beneficiary url", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.url();
      assert.equal(actual, url, "url should match");
    });

    it("gets the beneficiary image url", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.imageURL();
      assert.equal(actual, imageURL, "imageURL should match");
    });

    it("gets the beneficiary description", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.description();
      assert.equal(actual, description, "description should match");
    });

    it("gets the beneficiary", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.beneficiary();
      assert.equal(actual, beneficiary, "beneficiary addresses should match");
    });

    it("gets the owner", async () => {
      const actual = await fundraiser.owner();
      assert.equal(actual, owner, "bios should match");
    });
  });

  describe("setBeneficiary", () => {
    //The line where the error is pointed out
    const newBeneficiary = accounts[2];

    it("updated beneficiary when called by owner account", async () => {
      await fundraiser.setBeneficiary(newBeneficiary, { from: owner });
      const actualBeneficiary = await fundraiser.beneficiary();
      assert.equal(
        actualBeneficiary,
        newBeneficiary,
        "beneficiaries should match"
      );
    });

    it("throws and error when called from a non-owner account", async () => {
      try {
        await fundraiser.setBeneficiary(newBeneficiary, { from: accounts[3] });
        assert.fail("withdraw was not restricted to owners");
      } catch (err) {
        const expectedError = "Ownable: caller is not the owner";
        const actualError = err.reason;
        assert.equal(actualError, expectedError, "should not be permitted");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to clear up the problem. I just thought it was an accounts issue. I had not thought that the closing of the parentheses was the cause.thank you :)

Comment: @kintoki did it work?